# Can this Gstreamer pipeline be converted to FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

I would like to know if I can convert this GSTREAMER pipeline to a ffmpeg command:

`udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG2000, sampling=(string)GRAYSCALE, width=(int)1280, height=(int)480, payload=(int)96" ! rtpj2kdepay ! jpeg2000parse ! openjpegdec !  videoconvert ! appsink`

This is because I would prefer not to add another dependency to the project but I could not make it work. Not sure if its possible at all...